# 301 redirect code to new folder structure URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I use this redirect on my old site:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldfolder(/.*)?$ http://newsite.com/newfolder$1    [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

this redirect code help me:

- First,to redirect www to non www on my new site
- Second,to redirect oldsite URLs with oldfolder to newsite URLs with newfolder

The problem is that some old URLs have index.php on their structure and redirection is wrong. For example:

oldsite.com/index.php/oldfolder/....

redirect to

newsite.com/index.php/oldfolder/....

but the right redirection should be to

newsite.com/index.php/newfolder/....   or   newsite.com/newfolder/....

How can i change my redirect code to make the right redirections to my newfolder structure URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  the following rule to redirect from oldsite/ to newsite :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldfolder/(.*)$ http://newsite.com/newfolder/$1    [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```